# Can't set breakpoints in some source files

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I'm using Eclipse Mars on an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine running in VirtualBox. Currently I'm trying to debug initdb of postgresql after I've change some code. Now initdb is starting correctly in the debugger.

The problem: When I set a breakpoint in certain source files, this breakpoint gets set and the little blue dot appears in the column on the left of the editor. But: The gdb process prints the following error message on the console: "No source file named $P.", where $P equals the path of the source file, in which I set the breakpoint. Furthermore, the debugger doesn't halt the program execution at such a breakpoint.

This kind of problem I've seen quite a lot while I tried to find a solution, but what makes my situation different is this: The problem I described above doesn't appear with all source files in my project folder. It's only with some source files and in others I can set working breakpoints without any problem.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are some of them release builds and others debug builds?

Comment: @Thomas: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Where can I check that? But all source files I need for debugging belong to the same project.

Comment: Build mode is set to "Default" for the project.

Comment: assure all compile/link steps have NO optimization and all compile/link steps have the parameter -g (or for gcc -ggdb) .  Assure that the debugger has permissions to read all the source files, including the directories the source files are in.

Comment: I tried -ggdb option instead of -g, which I had set before in the makefiles. The src folder and all subdirectories have read and write permissions for any user.